# Rmarkdown error in eval, object not found

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been trying to knit my rmd file, but keep getting an error message

line 56 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'gol.fac' not found Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted

````
```{r}
data(golub, package = "multtest")
grep("Zyxin",golub.gnames[,2])
all <- golub[2124,gol.fac=="ALL"]
aml <- golub[2124,gol.fac=="AML"]
summary(all)
summary(aml)
```
````

Line 56 is the first line after the ```{r}. 
I am not sure why it is giving me errors, when I am able to run the code before knitting

Comment: Is `gol.fac` defined anywhere in the RMarkdown file? When you knit, it starts from a fresh workspace for the whole document (so it will not use the `gol.fac` that is in your workspace). Or if `golub` is a `data.table` (ie `gol.fac` is the name of the column), you will need to do this coercion in your RMarkdown too.

Comment: Further to: "`gol.fac` is the name of the column". If you `attach`'d `golub` and it worked before, it'll probably prevent future headaches if you explicitly refer to the `data.frame` and column: `golub[2124, golub$gol.fac=="ALL"]`